# Equivalence of PHP includes in Iphone dev?

Tags: iphone, optimization, class, redundancy

I just noticed I get a lot of redondant code from one class to another in my project (like menus or buttons) ;)

Is there any way to optimize it ?

Thank you !

Gotye.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is *#include* directive in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Use classes for common code.  Or refactor and base several classes on an abstract superclass.  Or use regular C functions.  Or use [categories](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) to add methods to library functions.